# In OAuth2 protocol browser does not include `ASP.NET_SessionId` cookie after authorization server redirects to the `redirect_uri`

Tags: asp.net, security, oauth, microsoft-graph-api, session-cookies

I have a problem that I have no idea how to solve.

I want to use OAuth2 and Microsoft's authorization server to get the access token with a set of permission for a user, that can be used to retrieve information from the OneDrive app via Microsoft Graph

I get stacked in the stage where `code` from the authorization server is obtained and then a call to the `secured` ASP.NET backend endpoint with that `code` should be executed.

From the simple button I `GET` the Microsoft OAuth endpoint (`login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`) with `redirect_uri` of my **secured** ASP.NET endpoint. The `response_type` is `code id_token` and the `respones_mode` is `form_post`. After all of the *OAuth dance* I get a `POST` call from the **Microsoft domain** (origin is `login.live.com`) with `id_token`, `code`, and `state`. The call is to the backend endpoint specified earlier in `redirect_uri`.

The point is that I have an active session (the user is already signed in) and I need a browser to include the `ASP.NET_SessionId` cookie in the request. The cookie's `SameSite` attribute is set to `Lax` in this case.

If I set the `SameSite` cookie attribute to `None` the endpoint can be reached. Otherwise, the browser prevents a potential CSRF attack and doesn't include the token, only endpoints with `[AllowAnonymous]` attributes can be reached which is unacceptable in my scenario.

What makes me think is the fact that the `Initiator` of the last call is `oauth20_authorize.srf`, in the case of other websites that uses OAuth2 it's usually `document`. I am not sure if is this the right track.

Thank you all in advance, hope someone might have a clue what's going on or maybe have a secure workaround solution.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way to make things work is to get rid of `response_mode = form_post`. The response mode redirects the user with the **POST** method, hence with the `SameSite=Lax` attribute it can not work. A browser won't attach the cookie, because browsers work that way.

As the Mozilla documentation states:

> With Strict, the browser only sends the cookie with requests from the cookie's origin site. **Lax is similar, except the browser also sends the cookie when the user navigates to the cookie's origin site (even if the user is coming from a different site).**

If one set `SameSite` to `None` the `form_post` response method will work. Of course, this solution is far from perfect, because of security vulnerabilities (CRFS attacks).

I have decided to change `response_mode` to `query`, decline the POST method and use GET instead. Talking about security it would be better to stay with POST, but I haven't found another way. The downside of the solution is that the code that will be exchanged for a token, will be stored in logs, browsers, and such. To make it more secure I implemented the PKCE (Proof Key for Code) and set `code` validity to 60 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a workaround. I've done what I can to secure it, but someone much smarter and security conscious is more than welcome to guide me.

I had the exact same issue using the MSAL.js npm package. I did not want to fall back to `query` (or `fragment` in the case of MSAL) as a response mode or change the `SameSite` value of my SessionID cookie.

The workaround I found is to, on the `redirect_uri`, when the post is received back from Microsoft, build a simple html `<form>` with hidden inputs for each of the form variables, then have a bit of javascript to repost the form when the page loads, and an extra variable just to specify that it was "resubmitted" (or you could potentially post to another URL on your site - this is just the way I did it).

If you do it this way, the SessionID cookie should be included in the second post, and your session should work (in my case I had a CSRF token which I wanted to verify).

The code that builds the form makes sure the keys and values of the form's inputs are escaped, and I threw in some sanitization regex to strip out anything not matching `/[^a-zA-Z0-9\-._=]/g`. I also have `Content-Security-Policy` headers which prevents the form from being submitted on load, which I solved with a nonce.

Here is the TypeScript code to generate the HTML for the resubmit form (I'm using Express):

```js
import { Request, Response } from "express";
import msal from "@azure/msal-node";
import * as he from "he";

const buildRepostForm = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const nonce = new msal.CryptoProvider().createNewGuid();

  res.set("Content-Security-Policy", `script-src 'nonce-${nonce}'`);

  let formString = `<form method="POST" name="resubmitForm" action="">`;

  req.body.resubmitted = "1";

  for (const key in req.body) {
    const escapedKey = he.escape(sanitizeInput(key || ""));
    const escapedValue = he.escape(sanitizeInput(req.body[key] || ""));
    formString += `<input type="hidden" name="${escapedKey}" value="${escapedValue}" />`;
  }

  formString += `</form><script nonce="${nonce}" type="text/javascript">document.forms[0].submit();</script>`;

  return formString;
};

function sanitizeInput(input: string) {
  return input.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\-._=]/g, "");
}
```